# What does the character `S` stand for in nosetest output

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose, nosetests

I am running python nosetests on a foreign module. The dots mean that a test passed. What does S stand for?

```
c:\vendor\test>nosetests
................................................................................
........................................SS......S.S.............................
.........SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS......S....SSSS.................S..S...SSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SSSSSSSSS.SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS..........SS.....SSSSSSS............
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 327 tests in 629.369s
```

This seems so obvios that it is hardly mentioned, could not find it in the docs, in the man page and not using google. Sorry I am not a python native.

Comment: I would imagine that dots roughly show elapsed time and `S` means success?

Comment: @AndréCaron Can't be, it ran 327 tests but only showed a few dozen S.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`S` means skipped, `.` means success.

http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/plugins/skip.html

> This plugin installs a SKIP error class for the SkipTest exception. When SkipTest is raised, the exception will be logged in the skipped attribute of the result, **‘S’ or ‘SKIP’ (verbose) will be output**, and the exception will not be counted as an error or failure.

Comment: Thank you ThiefMaster. I did not know about the plugin, as this is a foreign module. I was only going to make sure it passes in my environment.